# null is getting converted to "null" in Angular 5 HTTP get request

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am currently working on migrating our application from Angular 4 to Angular 5. In Angular 5 when we sending an object model as parameters and if one of the values has null then it is getting converted to "null" string. This is causing issues for us. The following is the way the parameters are being set:

```
options = {
                headers: header, params: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonParamObject)
                    .reduce((p, key) => p.set(key, jsonParamObject[key]), new HttpParams())
            };
```

In the above code we are using 'jsonParamObject' which is sent by the caller of this method. This object would have any number of values. So if the object has one of the value as null and when we are making an http request the value null is getting converted to "null" string. Could you please let me know how this can avoided or if there is any alternative.One of the alternatives would be to use "0" instead of null but that would require a lot of code changes in our application so I was looking for an easier/better approach.

Comment: Too much code! Just use `{params: jsonParamObject}`

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Yes I have tried using the jsonParamObject directly but it gives the same error. So it is not how we are passing the params. The value is automatically getting converted into null string.

Comment: @Valla you can replace the `null` values in the Object properties with "0" before setting `{params: jsonParamObject}`

Comment: @Niladri: Yes that is one of the alternatives that I mentioned in the question also. But that would require a lot of changes, so I wanted to know if that is the only approach or if there are any changes that I can do on the client side which would help me resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a property in an object. 
This property is called `parent_id` and the object is called `dataObj`.

To solve it, I used the following?

```
this.dataObj.parent_id = this.dataObj.parent_id == 'null' ? null : this.dataObj.parent_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue where i was trying to pass a string from the client side. it always got converted to "null" when i passed a null string.

Instead of passing the null string, i pass an empty string ("") which worked.